# Implementing user modifiable schema in mongoose

Tags: database, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm working on a MEAN stack CMS.
One of the features I'd like to implement is a user modifiable schema.
For instance, suppose you've got a user model, with the following mandatory fields:

- email
- name
- hashed password

At some point, the admin decides he wants to add fields for address and phone number.
The new (flat) model would look like so:

- email
- name
- hashed password
- address
- phone number

Is this feasible or should I just stick to an hard coded schema?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

> Data in MongoDB has a flexible schema. Collections do not enforce
>   document structure.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/

only modify the document adding new things and ready, new schema for that document.